# Pandas - Counting the number of days for group by

Tags: python, date, pandas, group-by

I want to count the number of days after grouping by 2 columns:

```
groups = df.groupby([df.col1,df.col2])
```

Now i want to count the number of days relevant for each group:

```
result = groups['date_time'].dt.date.nunique()
```

I'm using something similar when I want to group by day, but here I get an error:

> AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'dt' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

What is the proper way to get the number of days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another variation of [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby) - define column first:

```
df['date_time'].dt.date.groupby([df.col1,df.col2]).nunique()
```

---

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['date_time'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.date.nunique())
```

---

```
df['date_time1'] = df['date_time'].dt.date
a = df.groupby([df.col1,df.col2]).date_time1.nunique()
```

Sample:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10, freq='15H')

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': rng, 'col1': [0]*5 + [1]*5, 'col2': [2]*3 + [3]*4+ [4]*3})  
print (df)
   col1  col2           date_time
0     0     2 2015-02-24 00:00:00
1     0     2 2015-02-24 15:00:00
2     0     2 2015-02-25 06:00:00
3     0     3 2015-02-25 21:00:00
4     0     3 2015-02-26 12:00:00
5     1     3 2015-02-27 03:00:00
6     1     3 2015-02-27 18:00:00
7     1     4 2015-02-28 09:00:00
8     1     4 2015-03-01 00:00:00
9     1     4 2015-03-01 15:00:00
```

```
#solution with apply
df1 = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['date_time'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.date.nunique())
print (df1)
col1  col2
0     2       2
      3       2
1     3       1
      4       2
Name: date_time, dtype: int64

#create new helper column
df['date_time1'] = df['date_time'].dt.date
df2 = df.groupby([df.col1,df.col2]).date_time1.nunique()
print (df2)
col1  col2
0     2       2
      3       2
1     3       1
      4       2
Name: date_time, dtype: int64

df3 = df['date_time'].dt.date.groupby([df.col1,df.col2]).nunique()
print (df3)
col1  col2
0     2       2
      3       2
1     3       1
      4       2
Name: date_time, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This worked well. I don't get why Series doesn't have the dt attribute like Dataframe has.